# Taking from an element in a list prolog

Tags: prolog

Say I have a list

```
[5,4,6,9]
```

And I want to take away from the head of the list but return the rest of the list

so: -3

```
[2,4,6,9]
```

-2

```
[3,4,6,9]
```

And then I want to move on to the next element so,

-3

```
[5,1,6,9],
```

-2

```
[5,2,6,9]
```

How could I produce a prolog predicate for this,

so far I have

```
 change([],[]).
change([Head|Tail], [Head1|Tail]):-
    process(Head, Head1).


process([],[]).
process(Head, Head1):-
    Head1 is Head-3,
    Head1 >=0.

process(Head, Head1):-
    Head1 is Head-2,
    Head1 >=0.
```

I'm unsure what I'd return in my recursive call,
any help would be great thank you

Comment: You want to change only head and second element and leave other list as it is?   And also you want to do this only with -2,-3 or with a given number??

Comment: I want to remove -2 and -3 from each element in the list individually @coder

Comment: But in your example what should be the output with input [5,4,6,9]?? (you describe some changes but what is the expected output exactly??)

Comment: So I want it to show all possible states, so starting state is [5,4,6,9], then I want it to remove -2 and -3 from 5 individually so [3,4,6,9] , [2,4,6,9], [5,2,6,9] ,[5,1,6,9], [5,4,4,9] ,[5,4,3,9] [5,4,6,7] ,[5,4,6,6] @coder

Comment: @coder, the example I have added works perfectly for the first element, just unsure how to move on to the next one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your code is currently written it's attempting to change more than one list element in a given solution. However, the requirement appears to be to only change one list element. Using CLP(FD) will help with the arithmetic.

```
change([], []).           % Nothing to change
change([X|T], [Y|T]) :-   % Change only the head
    Y #= X - 2 ; Y #= X - 3.
change([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :- % Keep the head and change something later
    change(Xs, Ys).
```

The potential problem with this solution is that it `change(L, L).` is true (the list isn't changed). To avoid that, you can change the base case to be for the single element list and force the others to be two elements:

```
change([X], [Y]) :-             % Change only the last or single element
    Y #= X - 2 ; Y #= X - 3.
change([X,X1|Xs], [Y,X1|Xs]) :- % Change only the head
    Y #= X - 2 ; Y #= X - 3.
change([X,X1|Xs], [X,Y1|Ys]) :- % Keep the head and change something later
    change([X1|Xs], [Y1|Ys]).
```

Comment: Is this a common fix for avoiding this problem; by adding the extra element?\

Comment: @user3667111 adding the extra element is a way to force 2 or more elements in the list logic. I don't want the 2nd or 3rd clauses to match a single element list. I only want the first clause to match a single element list.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Also I know this may be trivial, but why put the `  ( Y is X - 2 ; Y is X - 3 )` in brackets?

Comment: @user3667111 good question! I guess I'm used to bracketing `;` due to its lower precedence versus `,`, but in this case it's not necessary. I'll update the answer for clarity.

Comment: Also is it necessary to use CLP(FD) ? is it not possible just to use Y is X -2?

Comment: @user3667111 you could use `is/2` but in Prolog CLP(FD) is considered the best approach because it's relational. `is/2` is imperative. For example, using CLP(FD), you can not only get solutions for `change([3,4,5], R)` but also `change([X,4,5], [4,4,5])`, but if you use `is/2` you will get an error.